# Conversion of Conditional Statement to Disjunctions

Tags: logic

Let us say that we have the conditional statement A→B. What would be the best way to represent that in the form of a disjunction (A∨B)? Help is much appreciated.

Comment: (A→B)<==>(¬A∨B)

Comment: So, how would I create a disjunctive syllogism out of the conditional If it is a difficulty, it strengthens the mind? The disjunction is ¬D∨SM. Correct?

Comment: Normally you use only one symbol for each statement so ¬D∨M would be my choice ... It's entirely the equivalent to D→M

Comment: This is called [Material Implication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_%28rule_of_inference%29).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're looking for some intellectual understanding of this:

What the statement "If A then B" means in logic is that there is never a case where A is true and B is false.  If A is true, then B will be true.

Another way of saying that is that either B will be true or A will be false. Therefore

!A V B

or

B V !A

are both alternate ways of expressing A -> B

You can confirm by assigning A and B values and confirming that the overall value of those three expressions always matches.

Comment: <nitpick> Some folks get picky about keeping symbols on the same sides of operators when changing the operator being used. If someone reading this has a logic professor who's a stickler about these sorts of things but they want to convert A->B to B V !A in preparation for a further operation, I recommend first converting to B V !A via Material Implication, *then* swapping sides via Commutation. </nitpick> My inner pedant satisfied, this was an excellent explanation that did a good job of explaining the *why* in addition to the *how*, and I thoroughly appreciate it.